# Measuring frequency with Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I am working on a small project for measuring input square wave frequency using Arduino, I did it using both timer and hardware interrupts and here is my code:

```
#include <TimerOne.h>
long count1=0,freq1=0;

void setup(){
    attachInterrupt(5,count,RISING);
    Timer1.initialize(1000000); //increments count for 1 sec and prints out count
    Timer1.attachInterrupt( freq ); // attach the service routine here

    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
    while(freq1)
        Serial.println(freq1);
}

void count()
{
    count1++; 
}

void freq(){
    freq1 =  count1;
    count1=0;
}
```

The problem is that output value is almost double the input frequency, 
I don't know what's wrong with it. I learned about interrupts after an intensive Google search. Seems it didn't work.

Comment: Probably, you are having troubles using interrupts and timers... When Arduino is handling an interrupt(execute count()) some functions of time are disabled or lost their sense. millis() or delay(), for example, don't work as usual if are called in a handler function.

Comment: What is `while(freq1)` for?

Comment: i dont want to print when freq1=0 so i set the loop

Answer (score 0):

There is a working example [here](https://github.com/cyberponk/PWM_Signal_Analyzer_for_Arduino/blob/master/PWM_Signal_Analyzer_for_Arduino.ino).
It uses native ISR functions (faster) instead of arduino interrupt handlers.
Uses Timer1 for best resolution and precision.

The code is big but the part that interests you is:

> ```
> The "// Setup Timer1 for precise timing" portion of void setup()
>
> ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) -> for timer1 overflow counter
>
> ISR(INT0_vect) // External Interrupt pin 2 [D2]
>
> void PulseCaptureScheduler_callback()  // Starts a capture and flags a timeout
>
> void PrintInfoScheduler_callback() // Processes the results
> ```